# Axios - Chrome and Edge won't send cookies back on localhost only on Firefox

Tags: reactjs, typescript, cookies, axios, session-cookies

My backend server runs on `https://localhost:5250` during development, and set session cookies when user logs in (according to the article Getting Token Authentication Right in a Stateless Single Page Application by Peter Locke).

- cookie1: domain: `localhost` path `/` is a `Session` and `Secure`
- cookie2: domain: `localhost` path `/` is a `Session` and `Secure` and `HttpOnly`

My nextJs frontent server runs on `http://localhost:3000`, therefore I added a cors policy to the backend. Therefore the **response headers* contains the following:

- Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
- Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000

Meanwhile the request header contains:

- Request URL: https://localhost:5250/Project/getProjects
- Request Method: POST
- Origin: http://localhost:3000

The backend server has an openapi/swagger definition, and using the `openapi-generator-cli` I generated an axios client for my **React app**, and I want it to send the cookies back in every API call setting the `withCredentials: true`. It works in Firefox, but won't work in Edge or Chrome.

```
const backendConfig = new Configuration({
    basePath: "https://localhost:5250",
});
const projectApi = new ProjectApi(backendConfig);
// calling getProjects() on project api controller
let projects = await projectApi.getProjects( {withCredentials:true} );
```

I also tried to set the property on the global axios instance:

```
import axios from 'axios';

axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
const backendConfig = new Configuration({
    basePath: "https://localhost:5250",
});
const projectApi = new ProjectApi(backendConfig);
// calling getProjects() on project api controller
let projects = await projectApi.getProjects();
```

The backend api says `no cookies were attached to the request`, and in the DevTools I also see that no cookies are attached to the api call.

I wonder what should I do to get the Axios to send it along with the call. Also why firefox works, chrome never, edge sometimes?

Comment: Seems the problem depens on that the backend runs on https:// and the frontend on http:// - still seems a little bit nonsense for me... but if both runs on http seems works on Edge also!